# Parse a yaml with placeholder in Java

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file which consist of placeholders to be taken from environment variable. I want to parse it to a custom class. Currently I am using snakeyaml library to parse it and its populating the bean correctly, how can I resolve environment variables using snakeyaml or any other library in Java.

```
datasource:
  url: {url_environment_variable}
  foo: bar
  username: {user_name_environment_variable}
  password: {password_environment_variable}

@Getter
@Setter
public class DataSource {
private String url;
private String foo;
private String username;
private String password;
}
```

Parsing code below

```
Constructor c = new Constructor(MyDataSource.class);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(c);
MyDataSource myData = yaml.loadAs(inputStream, MyDataSource.class);
```

The problem is I am yet to find a way to resolve placeholders. People were able to solve it using python and is available in question -
[How to replace environment variable value in yaml file to be parsed using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412297/how-to-replace-environment-variable-value-in-yaml-file-to-be-parsed-using-python)

How can I do the same in Java. I can add a new dependency if required.
PS - It's not a Spring Boot Project so standard Spring placeholder replacements can not be used.

Comment: I think you need an explicit getter with `System.getEnv()` inside.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to do it in two passes. First deserialize into `MyDataSource` as you’re doing already. Then use reflection to iterate over all fields of the instance, and if the value starts with a curly brace and ends with one, extract the key, and get the value from `System.getenv` map. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638662/839733) for code.

If you want to do it in one pass, then you need to use the snakeyaml event-driver parser. For every key, you resolve the value as described above, and then based on the key name, set the corresponding field in the `MyDataSource` class, either using reflection, or simple if-else. For an example of the event-driven parser, see [this class](https://github.com/asarkar/cassandra-unit-spring/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/asarkar/spring/test/cassandra/CassandraUnitApplicationListener.kt); it’s not Java, it’s Kotlin, but it may be the only JVM language example you’ll find.

Comment: No the above code and structure shown are just a part of it. It's rather more complex structure having placeholders in between

Comment: Sorry that I couldn’t read your mind to begin with, my bad.

Comment: Then do it the other way around: substitute your "placeholders" and then parse yaml regularly.